# Is it possible to use Spring EL when referencing a bean in constructor-arg?

Tags: java, spring, spring-el

```
<bean id="foo" class="com.bla.Foo" />
<bean id="bar" class="com.bla.Bar" />
<bean id="channel" class="com.bla.Channel">
    <constructor-arg ref="#{(config.isFooEnabled()) ? foo : bar}"/>
</bean>
```

I get the following error:

> Cannot resolve reference to bean  '#{(config.isFooEnabled()) ? foo : bar}'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ref` attribute value must be a string, not a reference itself, so, I would try returning `foo` or `bar` as a string, as in:

```
<constructor-arg ref="#{(config.isFooEnabled()) ? 'foo' : 'bar'}"/>
```

The spring beans engine will get the string returned by the expression, and resolve the reference.